# How can I make the <dd> items of a <dl> to be initially hidden via knockout's custom databinding?

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, knockout.js, custom-binding

I've created a `<dl>` where the `<dd>` can be `slideDown`/`slideUp` by a click on the corresponding `<dt>` by using knockout's databinding. *I derived my solution from the tutorial about [creating custom bindings](http://knockoutjs.com/documentation/custom-bindings.html).*

So far I managed to wire *everything* so that I can click on a `<dt>` and toggle the `<dd>`. The plan was to keep the `<dd>`s initially hidden but somehow I am not able achieve this.

Here's a simplified sample demonstrating the problem:

`HTML`:

```
<dl data-bind="foreach: items">
    <dt data-bind="click: toggleDefinition">DT: Lorem ipsum</dt>
    <dd data-bind="slideVisible: definitionVisible, slideDuration: 300">DD: dolor sit amet</dd>    
</dl>
```

`JavaScript`:

```
ko.bindingHandlers.slideVisible = {
    init: function (element, valueAccessor) {
        var value = ko.unwrap(valueAccessor());
        $(element).toggle(value);
    },
    update: function (element, valueAccessor, allBindings) {
        var value = ko.unwrap(valueAccessor());
        var duration = allBindings.get('slideDuration') || 400;
        if (value) {
            $(element).slideUp(duration);
        } else {
            $(element).slideDown(duration);
        }
    }
};

var model = function(){
    var self = this;
    self.items = ko.observableArray([
        new item(),
        new item(),
        new item()
    ]);
};

var item = function(){
    var self = this;
    self.definitionVisible = ko.observable(false);
    self.toggleDefinition = function (e)
    {
        self.definitionVisible(!self.definitionVisible());
    };
};

ko.applyBindings(new model());
```

What I've tried:

to hide the `<dd>`s by `CSS` but it doesn't work like I had hoped (I didn't notice any difference):

```
dd {
    display: none;
}
```

to set the following property to `true` - it partialy works - it hides the `<dd>`s but you can see the animation hiding them which is not desirable:

```
self.definitionVisible = ko.observable(true);
```

I also build a [*working* demo at jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/ju2ro0vz/1/)

Do you know what else I could try or change to keep the `<dd>`s hidden until I click on a `<dt>`?

I don't understand why the `update` function gets called that shows the items again. I was trying to find what triggers it but the call stack does not help much (everything comes from knockout which cannot be traced).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The update function is triggered correctly as described in the [documentation](http://knockoutjs.com/documentation/custom-bindings.html#the-update-callback):

> Knockout will call the update callback **initially** when the binding is applied to an element and track any dependencies (observables/computeds) that you access

Beside that your handler is not working because you missed some cases in your logic: you try to show/hide based on the current value but you should check the following instead:

- if the element is currently hidden and the new value of `definitionVisible` is `true` -> then show the element
- if the element is currently visible and the new value of `definitionVisible` is `false` -> then hide the element

Translating it to your code:

```
update: function (element, valueAccessor, allBindings) {
    var value = ko.unwrap(valueAccessor());
    var duration = allBindings.get('slideDuration') || 400;
    if ($(element).css('display') != 'none' && !value) {
        $(element).slideUp(duration);
    }
    if ($(element).css('display') == 'none' && value) {
        $(element).slideDown(duration);
    }
}
```

Demo [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/7zad4oLj/1/).

Comment: I knew I was missing something _simple_. Thank you ;-)